# How do you add one chart to the right of another?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two charts, and I would like to insert the data from one at the end of the other. However, the one chart has multiple ListLinePlots, and when I use Show to try and place the two together, the one shows at the very beginning. I would like it to make it seem like a continuation of the first chart, like a type of forecast. I hope this makes sense. Here are images of both the charts:

[image: Chart1]

Above is the first chart.

[image]

I would like to add this chart to the very end of the first chart, but am not sure how to do so. All the help will be very appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried with `Show[]` (i.e. code and pictures), and explain why the result is unsatisfactory to you?

Comment: Who told you to use `Show`? Just curious.

Comment: There are some many examples for this in the [documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0jz9y9fp6f2gie-i2hoip).

Comment: @Jackson, do you want to solve your real problem or learn how to combine these two pictures? If the former, you have to reformulate the question (give description of the past process and forecast data), if the latter, what scale of `t` do you want to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First preparing some demo data:

```
data1 = First@Normal@RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[.5], {0, 100}];
data2 = First@Normal@RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[.5], {0, 10}];
data3 = First@Normal@RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[.5], {0, 10}];
data4 = First@Normal@RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[.5], {0, 10}];
{data2, data3, data4} =
  {data2, data3, data4} /. {a_Integer, b_} :> {a, b + data1[[-1, 2]]};

ListLinePlot[data1]
ListLinePlot[{data2, data3, data4}]
```

[image]

Now attaching the projections to the data:

```
{data2, data3, data4} =
  {data2, data3, data4} /. {a_Integer, b_} :> {a + data1[[-1, 1]], b};

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can show both chart in same frame but first chart with lower opacity. 
or using Row.

```
f1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 400,PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]];
f2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 400];
Row[{f1, f2}]
Show[{f1, f2}]
```